# Dual monitor setup in Ubuntu 10.10: I want a workspace on one screen and another on the other screen

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got dual monitors (TwinView) on Ubuntu 10.10 (remember: xorg.conf has mysteriously disappeared). I want a workspace on one screen and another on the other screen.
Is it possible to do this? I'm using an Nvidia card and the proprietary drivers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, XMONAD supports this extremely well. I couldnt imagine not working with 1 workspace per physical screen any more. Learning curve is steep admittedly, but its most productive desktop by far..

Comment: Whilst I'll look into that, I think ideally I'd rather stick with the Gnome desktop. That kind of WM would be for home use, where I can fiddle. This is for work, where I can't. Thanks though, good suggestion.

Comment: can you provide a ref for how to set up Xmonad like this?

Comment: Out the box xmonad config is 1 workspace per physical screen. You can also use Xmonad with GNOME and it works rather well. When I started my xmonad config was 12 lines, now I am gradually tweaking it with the help of guides like http://www.nepherte.be/howto-step-by-step-configuration-of-xmonad/

Comment: @Muu, Gnome window manager is metacity which doesnt support such scenario, so if you can't fiddle you are pretty much stuck. XMonad can be installed in your local directory and as long as you can modify your .xsession its ready to go